# MultiThreading with python and and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, python-multithreading

I would need advice how to use multithreading with python. I'm currently using the concurrent.futures librairy but the results i got seem to be slower than expected.

Here an example :
[image]

I need to compute this function a huge quantity of times so would need to reduce the computation time. Without multithreading it takes around 2.4 seconds to compute. I would like to reduce this number under 1.

I'm working on a dataframe of 50 rows, using multiprocess here is not relevant because of the fact that ditributing the data on the cpus would takes longer than needed.

This is why i was thinking about multithreading, but in the example i provide, threading even with 10 threads takes longer than without threading. What am i doing wrong ?

i already took a look to additionnal librairies but i would like to stay with natives librairies such as concurrent.futur if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Copy and paste the code into the question body as text, i cannot copy-paste a picture into my IDE, furthermore you need to create a minimal example of the inputs that the people can copy paste and run to be able to help you.

Comment: Threading inevitably involves some increased overhead computation and anyway cannot speed things up in this case. You should look at optimizing your code: use a vectorized approach rather than `iterrows`, use a profiler etc.